# Removing "Compare" from my template in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, compare

Each product has a "Add to Compare" link with it and the catalog list page has a "Compare Products" section in the sidebar. I want to remove all trace of compare functionality in my template.

All the answers and help have been on Magento 1.* versions. They don't work in Magento 2.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite new to Magento2, but I think you should look into `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/products/list/items.phtml`.

Search for `$showCompare`. Just set it to `false`, should work.

Comment: Wow, it's really hard coded in the templates, I don't see any other way either, except overriding `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare` and let all the `get*Url()` methods return an empty string.

Comment: Yep, same conclusion. I think it would be better to override template file since it is an "aesthetic" modification. $showCompare = false; after the switch.

Comment: Agreed, under this conditions. I was just baffled that you cannot configure it, not even via layout XML action.

Comment: Quite weird... but AFAIK they are still hardowrking on making all the code compliant with the guidelines. So maybe in the next future.